# Twitter API Direct Messages

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to write a script that will send a message to new followers using POST direct_messages/new. My account access level is read,write and direct messages but I am getting "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource" with code:220. I am not sure why this is. Am I missing something?